# Trello C# REST-API update CustomField with JSON-String

Tags: c#, json, custom-fields, rest, trello

I am writing a front-end for our trello in C# (DotNet 4.8).
So far, creating and updating a Card with CustomFields is working.

This is my Set/Update Method for CustomFields:

```
 public async Task SetCustomField(string card_id, string customFieldID, string text, string key, string token)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            string sUrl = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + card_id + "/customField/" + customFieldID + "/item?key=" + key + "&token=" + token;
            string _text = "{\"value\": {\"text\": \"" + @text + "\" }}";

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"), sUrl))
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content - Type", "application/json");
                request.Content = new StringContent(_text);
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
                    MessageBox.Show("URL: " + sUrl + "\nCustomFieldID: " + customFieldID + "\nText: " + @text + "\nResponse: " + response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have a specific customField which needs to be filled with a JSON-String.
For example:

[{"from":"03.05.2021 00:00:00","to":"03.05.2021 00:02:00","ae":"8","rideCosts":"True","Log":"asdasdasd"}, {"from":"03.05.2021 00:09:00","to":"03.05.2021 00:10:00","ae":"4","rideCosts":"True","Log":"qweqweqwe"}]

In trello, this specific customField is a TEXT-field.

When I try to update this specific customField I get an Error back: "Error parsing body".
I tried different contentTypes for this specific customField and manipulating the string "text" with no success.

Any suggestions?

P.S.: When I copy/paste the example string from above directly in the trello-card, it works perfectly and I can read and deserialze the JSON string in another method perfectly.
I just cannot PUT it in there...

P.P.S.:
I am using fallowing USING-directives:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.Json;
```

Comment: Content - Type  is really wrong.....you don't want spaces  you want   Content-Type   infact there are predefined types with all the standard header types, you also want to specify your Accept.....   but to make your life way simpler, just use RestSharp

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I corrected the "Content-Type" to the fallowing: ` request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json;masked=false");` But no success. Will look into RESTSHARP.